# md-select attribute name error Angular-Material

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Im working with angularjs/1.3.6 and v0.10.0/angular-material.js with a md-select field with name="txtGenero" but when the form have been Submitted with ajax the md-selected has a dot at beginning of name field like '.txtGenero' in the image below.

https://plus.google.com/photos/+TommyHern%C3%A1ndezA/albums/6175087393788917697/6175087392180342338?pid=6175087392180342338&oid=118016940134163401130

I hope can help me thanks.

Comment: Can you add your code dirrectly in your question?

Comment: you can see it here http://plnkr.co/edit/lruvcj9I1EFI1uUiJoxz?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know why the `ngFormController` has the `.txtGenero` field.
However you should use `ngModel` to bind your form fields to a model and post that model, not the form controller itself. You can use `angular.element.param($scope.registro)` to get the the fields from your model as form data.
You don't need jQuery for any of it.

Updated plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/IFOsFgiQBo7vJVzkBxaf?p=preview
(I updated to angular-material master)

Try to provide your code well formatted, this is kind of a mess to work with.

Comment: Yes I did this way $scope.registro.txtTipo to bind the value